# Why isn't BeautifulSoup scraping the entire webpage?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Premise: I am totally new to Python and web scraping. I am trying to scrape the data about the brands on this page: https://www.interbrand.com/best-brands/best-global-brands/2018/ranking/ , but BeautifulSoup extracts the html only up to a certain point. Nothing strange seems to be in the html there, as there are five almost equal tags before that one that BeautifulSoup extracts without any problem.

I already tried using three different parsers (the built-in one, lxml and html5lib), but I always get the same result.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
page = requests.get("https://www.interbrand.com/best-brands/best-global-brands/2018/ranking/")
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content , 'html5lib')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: What information do you want to scrape from that page?

Comment: The rankings of the brands and the data relative to them (country, region, sector)

Comment: I can perfectly extract all these data starting with your code.

Comment: When I print "soup.prettify()", I get only the html related to the header, it abruptly stops like this:

<div class="col-25 base-margin-bottom">
         <a class="location hover-red text-medium leading-small" data-location="Sydney" data-path="/au/" href="/au/">
          Sydney
         </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-25 base-margin-bottom">
         <a class="location hover-red text-medium leading-small" dat

While the data about the rankings is in the next tag...

Comment: What version of `python`, `requests` and `bs4` do you use?

Comment: @sentence, same here. I too cannot reproduce this. I am getting entire page too here.

Comment: @sentence I'm using python 3.7.2, requests 2.21.0 and bs4 4.7.1

Comment: code works for me too. Python 3.7.3/Request 2.21.0/bs4 4.7.1/Linux Mint 19.1. You may check `page.content` to see if you have all in HTML.

Comment: @BlancheT What happens using `page = requests.get("https://www.interbrand.com/best-brands/best-global-brands/2018/ranking/").text`, `soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')`? Still not working?

Comment: @sentence Yes, same exact result, it stops at the same point

Comment: Let's wait for other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Use Css selecor to get the output.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("https://www.interbrand.com/best-brands/best-global-brands/2018/ranking/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content , 'lxml')
Brand=[]
Country=[]
Region=[]
Sector=[]
for brnd in soup.select('div.brand-name'):
    Brand.append(brnd['title'])

for region in soup.select('div.brand-region'):
    Region.append(region['title'])

for county in soup.select('div.brand-country'):
    Country.append(county['title'])

for sector in soup.select('div.brand-sector'):
    Sector.append(sector['title'])

print(Brand)
print(Region)
print(Country)
print(Sector)
```

Output:

```
['Brand name: Apple', 'Brand name: Google', 'Brand name: Amazon', 'Brand name: Microsoft', 'Brand name: Coca-Cola', 'Brand name: Samsung', 'Brand name: Toyota', 'Brand name: Mercedes-Benz', 'Brand name: Facebook', "Brand name: McDonald's", 'Brand name: Intel', 'Brand name: IBM', 'Brand name: BMW', 'Brand name: Disney', 'Brand name: Cisco', 'Brand name: GE', 'Brand name: Nike', 'Brand name: Louis Vuitton', 'Brand name: Oracle', 'Brand name: Honda', 'Brand name: SAP', 'Brand name: Pepsi', 'Brand name: Chanel', 'Brand name: American Express', 'Brand name: Zara', 'Brand name: J.P. Morgan', 'Brand name: IKEA', 'Brand name: Gillette', 'Brand name: UPS', 'Brand name: H&M', 'Brand name: Pampers', 'Brand name: Hermès', 'Brand name: Budweiser', 'Brand name: Accenture', 'Brand name: Ford', 'Brand name: Hyundai', 'Brand name: NESCAFÉ', 'Brand name: eBay', 'Brand name: Gucci', 'Brand name: Nissan', 'Brand name: Volkswagen', 'Brand name: Audi', 'Brand name: Philips', 'Brand name: Goldman Sachs', 'Brand name: Citi', 'Brand name: HSBC', 'Brand name: AXA', "Brand name: L'Oréal", 'Brand name: Allianz', 'Brand name: adidas', 'Brand name: Adobe', 'Brand name: Porsche', "Brand name: Kellogg's", 'Brand name: HP', 'Brand name: Canon', 'Brand name: Siemens', 'Brand name: Starbucks', 'Brand name: Danone', 'Brand name: Sony', 'Brand name: 3M', 'Brand name: Visa', 'Brand name: Nestlé', 'Brand name: Morgan Stanley', 'Brand name: Colgate', 'Brand name: Hewlett Packard Enterprise', 'Brand name: Netflix', 'Brand name: Cartier', 'Brand name: Huawei', 'Brand name: Banco Santander', 'Brand name: Mastercard', 'Brand name: Kia', 'Brand name: FedEx', 'Brand name: PayPal', 'Brand name: LEGO', 'Brand name: Salesforce.com', 'Brand name: Panasonic', 'Brand name: Johnson & Johnson', 'Brand name: Land Rover', 'Brand name: DHL', 'Brand name: Ferrari', 'Brand name: Discovery', 'Brand name: Caterpillar', 'Brand name: Tiffany & Co.', "Brand name: Jack Daniel's", 'Brand name: Corona', 'Brand name: KFC', 'Brand name: Heineken', 'Brand name: John Deere', 'Brand name: Shell', 'Brand name: MINI', 'Brand name: Dior', 'Brand name: Spotify', 'Brand name: Harley-Davidson', 'Brand name: Burberry', 'Brand name: Prada', 'Brand name: Sprite', 'Brand name: Johnnie Walker', 'Brand name: Hennessy', 'Brand name: Nintendo', 'Brand name: Subaru']
['Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Asia Pacific', 'Region: Asia Pacific', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Asia Pacific', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Asia Pacific', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: Asia Pacific', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Asia Pacific', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: Asia Pacific', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: Asia Pacific', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Asia Pacific', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Asia Pacific', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: The Americas', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: Europe & Africa', 'Region: Asia Pacific', 'Region: Asia Pacific']
['Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: South Korea', 'Country: Japan', 'Country: Germany', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: Germany', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: France', 'Country: United States', 'Country: Japan', 'Country: Germany', 'Country: United States', 'Country: France', 'Country: United States', 'Country: Spain', 'Country: United States', 'Country: Sweden', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: Sweden', 'Country: United States', 'Country: France', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: South Korea', 'Country: Switzerland', 'Country: United States', 'Country: Italy', 'Country: Japan', 'Country: Germany', 'Country: Germany', 'Country: Netherlands', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United Kingdom', 'Country: France', 'Country: France', 'Country: Germany', 'Country: Germany', 'Country: United States', 'Country: Germany', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: Japan', 'Country: Germany', 'Country: United States', 'Country: France', 'Country: Japan', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: Switzerland', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: France', 'Country: China', 'Country: Spain', 'Country: United States', 'Country: South Korea', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: Denmark', 'Country: United States', 'Country: Japan', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United Kingdom', 'Country: United States', 'Country: Italy', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United States', 'Country: Mexico', 'Country: United States', 'Country: Netherlands', 'Country: United States', 'Country: Netherlands', 'Country: United Kingdom', 'Country: France', 'Country: Sweden', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United Kingdom', 'Country: Italy', 'Country: United States', 'Country: United Kingdom', 'Country: France', 'Country: Japan', 'Country: Japan']
['Sector: Technology', 'Sector: Technology', 'Sector: Retail', 'Sector: Technology', 'Sector: Beverages', 'Sector: Technology', 'Sector: Automotive', 'Sector: Automotive', 'Sector: Technology', 'Sector: Restaurants', 'Sector: Technology', 'Sector: Business Services', 'Sector: Automotive', 'Sector: Media', 'Sector: Technology', 'Sector: Diversified', 'Sector: Sporting Goods', 'Sector: Luxury', 'Sector: Technology', 'Sector: Automotive', 'Sector: Technology', 'Sector: Beverages', 'Sector: Luxury', 'Sector: Financial Services', 'Sector: Apparel', 'Sector: Financial Services', 'Sector: Retail', 'Sector: FMCG', 'Sector: Logistics', 'Sector: Apparel', 'Sector: FMCG', 'Sector: Luxury', 'Sector: Alcohol', 'Sector: Business Services', 'Sector: Automotive', 'Sector: Automotive', 'Sector: Beverages', 'Sector: Retail', 'Sector: Luxury', 'Sector: Automotive', 'Sector: Automotive', 'Sector: Automotive', 'Sector: Electronics', 'Sector: Financial Services', 'Sector: Financial Services', 'Sector: Financial Services', 'Sector: Financial Services', 'Sector: FMCG', 'Sector: Financial Services', 'Sector: Sporting Goods', 'Sector: Technology', 'Sector: Automotive', 'Sector: FMCG', 'Sector: Technology', 'Sector: Electronics', 'Sector: Diversified', 'Sector: Restaurants', 'Sector: FMCG', 'Sector: Electronics', 'Sector: Diversified', 'Sector: Financial Services', 'Sector: FMCG', 'Sector: Financial Services', 'Sector: FMCG', 'Sector: Technology', 'Sector: Media', 'Sector: Luxury', 'Sector: Technology', 'Sector: Financial Services', 'Sector: Financial Services', 'Sector: Automotive', 'Sector: Logistics', 'Sector: Financial Services', 'Sector: FMCG', 'Sector: Business Services', 'Sector: Electronics', 'Sector: FMCG', 'Sector: Automotive', 'Sector: Logistics', 'Sector: Automotive', 'Sector: Media', 'Sector: Diversified', 'Sector: Luxury', 'Sector: Alcohol', 'Sector: Alcohol', 'Sector: Restaurants', 'Sector: Alcohol', 'Sector: Diversified', 'Sector: Energy', 'Sector: Automotive', 'Sector: Luxury', 'Sector: Media', 'Sector: Automotive', 'Sector: Luxury', 'Sector: Luxury', 'Sector: Beverages', 'Sector: Alcohol', 'Sector: Alcohol', 'Sector: Electronics', 'Sector: Automotive']
```

Comment: The question is not about **how** to do something, but **why** something does not work.

Comment: @sentence : When I read the comment I thought OP unable to fetch those values so I posted the code.